# Admob doesn't load ads for iOS 10 iMessage app extension

Tags: ios, admob, ios-app-extension, ios10, imessage

Instead, just a blank view is appearing.

Here's how I load the ad request:

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-9213331484438711~8534798836") // actual app id
bannerView.delegate = self
bannerView.rootViewController = self
bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeLargeBanner
// unit id taken from guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start
// Actual unit id doesn't work either.
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kDFPSimulatorID]
bannerView.layoutIfNeeded()
bannerView.load(request)
```

I've set `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES`, but this didn't help. Delegate methods don't even get called. Am I missing something? Has anyone been able to get Admob working in an iMessage extension?

A sample project can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6agzpK_lR6JT1FPYjRQb2VDR00/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Ever figure this out? Or did you choose a different ad network...

Comment: @edelaney05 nope, still don't know what to do.

Comment: Any news on this one?

Comment: Admob banner ads didn't work for me either inside of an iMessage app. Had better luck with using [native ads](https://www.applovin.com) where you have more control over how the ads are displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it is possible to have ads in an app extension. Either way, there is a review guideline prohibiting it. From [iAds don't work in Action Extension or Share Extension?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27507):

> Review criteria 25.3: 
>   https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#advertising
>
> - 25.3: Apps hosting extensions that include marketing, advertising, or in-app purchases in their extension view will be rejected

Comment: Is this criteria about *apps hosting extensions*, not extensions themselves? Otherwise, what's the point of creating extensions if you are unable to monetize them.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev Its about the actual extensions it sounds like, "***in** their extension view will be rejected*". For example, having an application that displays ads is ok, but having the applications embedded today extension/notification center widget display ads is not.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev The point is good user experience. Find other ways to monetize.

Comment: @LeoNatan You are both referring to the old guideline. Please check out your link, it doesn't have such criteria. The correct link would be: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/#extensions which is an archive link.

Comment: It should be noted that this is about Apple Extensions, *not* iMessage Apps which have their own set of standards laid out by Apple. (Haven't seen any rulings on ads but they *DO* allow for in-app purchases (unlike stand-alone extensions)

Answer (score 1):

While this is not an answer to the question asked, I want to point out that review criteria 25.3 wasn't written with iMessage apps in mind. From [iMessage app FAQ](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/iMessage%20Apps%20and%20Sticker%20Packs_Overview).

> Can my iMessage app or sticker pack have in-app purchases?
>
> You may implement in-app purchases for your iMessage app or iOS apps
>   with an iMessage extension.

This explicitly allows in-app purchases (which are forbidden by 25.3) although it does not say anything about advertising.  Once AdMob or another ad library is working with an iMessage extension I believe it would be worth a try to submit the app.

Comment: Has anyone been able to add ads with admob or any other network thus far? It's been a while since this thread was updated

Answer (score 1):

From the AdMob team as of Aug 7, 2017:

> Thanks for reaching out to us. Our SDK does not support Messages
>   extension. You can keep an eye out for our release notes or monitor
>   our blogs if this ever changes.
>
> Regards, Deepika Uragayala Mobile Ads SDK Team